# Can I use javascript with in an Android App

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart

I am a real beginner in flutter and dart, i am trying to implement some web page (specifically pandemic.events) functionality with in a really simple android app..

my first thought is just to copy the web page with all of its' javascript inside the app and manipulate a little bit some parts that i find lacking.

i am struggling with using javascript inside my flutter app (writing import package:js... in main.dart).

Is there even a possibility to use javascript inside a flutter android app ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use JavaScript code and packages in your Flutter code with https://pub.dev/packages/js

Comment: I tried that and that didn't quite work... (again I am trying to implement js into an android app not a web app). can you post a code snippet that demonstrates it ? with all of it dependencies... ?

Comment: Hi, this is an example https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Flutter but you can implement web page functionalities in a Progressive Web App which is a JavaScript technique to build mobile Apps both for Android and iOS